# Where are the placeholders used?

Tags: typo3

```
10 = FLUIDTEMPLATE
10 {
    file = fileadmin/templates/vorlage-v1.html

    variables {
        logo = IMAGE
        logo {
            file = fileadmin/images/logo.png
            file.width = 200
            params = class="logo"
            
            sourceCollection {
                small {
                    width = 200
                    srcsetCandidate = 1x
                }
                big {
                    width = 200
                    pixelDensity = 2
                    srcsetCandidate = 2x
                }
            }
            
            layoutKey = srcset
            layout {
                srcset {
                    element = <img src="###SRC###" srcset ="###SOURCECOLLECTION###" ###PARAMS### ###ALTPARAMS###>
                    source = |*|###SRC### ###SRCSETCANDIDATE###,|*|###SRC### ###SRCSETCANDIDATE###
                }
            }
        }
        
        brandLineFirst = TEXT
        brandLineFirst.value = Snowboardschule
    
        brandLineSecond = TEXT
        brandLineSecond.value = Meyer, Müller & Schmidt
      
        today = TEXT
        today.data = date:d.m.Y
        # today.wrap = <b> | </b>
        
        labelNews = TEXT
        labelNews.value = Aktuelles
      
        labelToday = TEXT
        labelToday.value = Heute ist der
      
    }
}
```

Hello! Please see the TypoScript-Code above. There are many placeholders used, like ###SRC### or ###SOURCECOLLECTION###. What I know is, that this structure ist for one and the same iamge, used with different resolutions. But where are these placeholders used, what fills them? The filename of the image is different, and the placeholders are also not in the html-fluid-template. Where are their Counterparts?
Greetings, Strawk

Answer (score 0):

You can find an explanation in the [manual](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/10.4/en-us/ContentObjects/Image/Index.html#sourcecollection).

If you use a source set for an image you have different resolutions. These resolutions are defined above (`sourceCollection`) and you have multiple `img`tags, for different window sizes.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't think that's the answer to my question. I asked about the placeholders. The elements of the code ### SRC ### and ### SOURCECOLLECTION ### are placeholders? I mean yes. Where are they filled? What are they filled with? There must be corresponding counterparts somewhere in the TYPO3 system.

Comment: follow my link and scroll up some lines

Answer (score 0):

The counter parts are in TYPO3 core image rendering:
https://github.com/TYPO3/TYPO3.CMS/blob/master/typo3/sysext/frontend/Classes/ContentObject/ImageContentObject.php

The description of the placeholder can be found as Bernd wrote:
https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/10.4/en-us/ContentObjects/Image/Index.html#layout-layoutkey-source